# Kähler structure on open complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is it always possible to put a compatible Kähler metric on an open complex manifold (non-compact, without boundary, say of finite topological type)?

**Edit 1**: Michael Albanese pointed out a nice counterexample (namely the punctured Hopf surface) when this is impossible for topological reasons. **Question**: Would it be possible to have counter-examples of the following unpleasant type: The underlying open manifold has a Kähler metric, but for a given complex structure we cannot find a compatible Kähler metric?

**Edit 2**: Misha pointed out there is a Kahler metric on punctured $S^3 \times S^1$. Thinking more about this, I cannot resist to ask one final variation. **Question** Does there exist an open complex manifold for which there is no Kahler metric on the underlying smooth manifold?

Comment: A Hopf surface with a point removed does not admit a Kähler metric, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/88996/21564).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The punctured Hopf surface is also an example for the revised question. It is easy to see that the Hopf surface $X$ is parallelizable (since it is diffeomorphic to $S^3\times S^1$); hence, $M=X- \{x\}$ admits an immersion in $R^4={\mathbb C}^2$ (Hirsch-Smale theory). Now pull-back the standard (flat) Kahler structure from ${\mathbb C}^2$ to $M$ via the immersion. On the other hand, as noted in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/88996/21564) mentioned by Michael Albanese in his comment, the standard complex structure on $M$ does not admit a compatible Kahler metric.

Answer (score 6):

In this G&T [paper](https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.2017.21.2461) there are examples of complex structures on $\Bbb R^4$ withouth compatible Kähler metrics. The point is that in this $(\Bbb R^4, J)$ there are holomorphic elliptic compact curves, so there are no compatible symplectic structures.

On the other hand, any smooth connected oriented noncompact 4-manifold admits both Kähler and non-Kähler complex structures (cf. this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08471)). I do not know about higher dimensions, regarding your last question.